# Proper syntax for array of INET values

Tags: arrays, postgresql, syntax

I have created a simple table that has arrays of `INET` fields:

```
CREATE TABLE nettable (id integer, source inet[], destination inet[]);
```

I can create the table, but when I try to insert data I always get a syntax error.

I have tried this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO nettable (id, source, destination)
VALUES (1, [ ’10.10.10.0/24’ ], [ ‘1.2.3.4/32’ ]);
```

And this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO nettable (id, source, destination)
VALUES (1,’{"10.10.10.0/24"}',’{"1.2.3.4/32"}');
```

Both times it complains about a syntax near the brackets.
What's the right syntax?

Comment: Use apostrophes (`'`) for quoting, not those weird `’`

Comment: `array['10.10.10.0/24', '1.2.3.4/32']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second attempt is close. But use plain single quotes **`'`** - a.k.a. ["Apostrophe"](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/39):

```
INSERT INTO nettable (id, source, destination)
VALUES (1, '{"10.10.10.0/24"}', '{"1.2.3.4/32"}');
```

Double-quotes would only be needed to eliminate ambiguity. So not in this case:

```
INSERT INTO nettable (id, source, destination)
VALUES (1, '{10.10.10.0/24}', '{1.2.3.4/32}');
```

This `’` is a ["Right Single Quotation Mark"](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/8217).